# jOOQ: convert Field in select statement from type1 to type2

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I have a statement like this:

```
SelectSelectStep<Record14<
    String, String, String, Timestamp, String, String, String, Integer, 
    Timestamp, String, String, String, Integer, DayToSecond>> select = create.select(
    TECHNICAL_WORK.NUMBER, TECHNICAL_CODE.CODE, TECHNICAL_CODE.DESCRIPTION,
    twLog.START_TIME, twStartLog.CODE, twStartLog.FIRST_NAME, twStartLog.LAST_NAME, twStartLog.CATEGORY,
    twLog.STOP_TIME, twEndLog.CODE, twEndLog.FIRST_NAME, twEndLog.LAST_NAME, twEndLog.CATEGORY,
    DSL.timestampDiff(twLog.STOP_TIME, twLog.START_TIME)
);
```

the last field is of type `Field<DayToSecond>` and I need to convert it to `Field<Double>` using DayToSecond.totalMinutes()

I can't find an api like this, eg:

```
DSL.timestampDiff(twLog.STOP_TIME, twLog.START_TIME).map( from -> from.totalMinutes() )
```

Can I do this conversion somehow?

Comment: Now that I think about it, this expression is for creating a query string. So transforming results should come after fetching them, which is possible using .fetch.stream().map(....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comments, you cannot convert the type of a jOOQ expression by providing instructions on how to map types after fetching (although that does look interesting, I have created a feature request for this: [#7100](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7100)).

You have several options:

#### Attach a converter to your expression

This works like the feature request [#7100](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/7100) but is more clumsy:

```java
Field<DayToSecond> diff = DSL.timestampDiff(
    DSL.currentTimestamp(), 
    DSL.timestamp("2018-01-01 00:00:00")
);

Field<Double> d = DSL.field("{0}", diff.getDataType()
                                       .asConvertedDataType(Converter.ofNullable(
    DayToSecond.class,
    Double.class,
    DayToSecond::getTotalMinutes,
    m -> DayToSecond.valueOf(m * 60000) // Optional implementation here
)), diff);

System.out.println(create.select(d).fetchOne());
```

#### Convert the value after fetching

Of course, you can also simply fetch a `DayToSecond` value and then convert the jOOQ `Result` using any tool of your preference, including:

- [`Result.map(RecordMapper)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Result.html#map-org.jooq.RecordMapper-)
- `Result.stream()`

Comment: I don't understand the use of "DSL.using(cn)" and how this will integrate with my solution (I don't see where the conversion is made).

Comment: `DSL.using(cn)` is not related to the conversion. For the avoidance of doubt, I've replaced it back with `create` as in your question. The conversion is made when the field `d` is fetched from the JDBC `ResultSet`, because its data type has an attached `Converter`. You can put a breakpoint in `DayToSecond::getTotalMinutes` and step through the logic to see what's happening